# Error when need to add pallet-assets in substrate

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template

I want to add `pallet-assets` in substrate runtime.rs .

[Repository](https://github.com/dortajkianoush/substrate_dex)

I did these steps:

1 -  add pallet-assets into `Cargo.toml` :

```rs
    pallet-assets = { default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }


    "pallet-assets/std",
```

2 - add these configs into runtime file :

```rs
    pub type AssetBalance = Balance;
    pub type AssetId = u32;
    
    parameter_types! {
        pub const AssetDeposit: Balance = 10 * UNITS; // 10 UNITS deposit to create fungible asset class
        pub const AssetAccountDeposit: Balance = deposit(1, 16);
        pub const ApprovalDeposit: Balance = EXISTENTIAL_DEPOSIT;
        pub const AssetsStringLimit: u32 = 50;
        pub const MetadataDepositBase: Balance = deposit(1, 68);
        pub const MetadataDepositPerByte: Balance = deposit(0, 1);
    }
    
    impl pallet_assets::Config for Runtime {
        type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
        type Balance = Balance;
        type AssetId = u32;
        type AssetIdParameter = u32;
        type CreateOrigin = AsEnsureOriginWithArg<frame_system::EnsureSigned<AccountId>>;
        type Currency = Balances;
        type ForceOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
        type AssetDeposit = AssetDeposit;
        type MetadataDepositBase = MetadataDepositBase;
        type MetadataDepositPerByte = MetadataDepositPerByte;
        type ApprovalDeposit = ApprovalDeposit;
        type RemoveItemsLimit = ConstU32<1000>;
        type StringLimit = AssetsStringLimit;
        type Freezer = ();
        type Extra = ();
        type WeightInfo = ();
        type AssetAccountDeposit = AssetAccountDeposit;
    
        #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
        type BenchmarkHelper = ();
    }
```

and final add `pallet-assets` file into the constructor:

```rs
    Assets: pallet_assets,
```

after I run this command `cargo check` it faced 116 errors:

I don't know what the problems are? How can I solves these problems?

```rs
        error: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on): `panic_impl`.
        |
        = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on)
        = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/target/debug/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-ff5bbb618e892e0d.rmeta
        = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/target/debug/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-9869b6e941266003.rmeta
    
      error: duplicate lang item in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on): `oom`.
        |
        = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `sp_io` (which `frame_support` depends on)
        = note: first definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/target/debug/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-ff5bbb618e892e0d.rmeta
        = note: second definition in `sp_io` loaded from /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/target/debug/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libsp_io-9869b6e941266003.rmeta
    
      error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied
         --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:283:6
          |
      283 | impl pallet_assets::Config for Runtime {
          |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `frame_system::pallet::Config` is not implemented for `Runtime`
          |
      note: required by a bound in `pallet_assets::Config`
         --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/2a0eeff/frame/assets/src/lib.rs:201:37
          |
      201 |     pub trait Config<I: 'static = ()>: frame_system::Config {
          |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `pallet_assets::Config`
    
      error[E0277]: the trait bound `pallet_assets::Pallet<Runtime>: Callable<Runtime>` is not satisfied in `RuntimeCall`
         --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:308:11
          |
      308 |         Block = Block,
          |                 ^^^^^ within `RuntimeCall`, the trait `Callable<Runtime>` is not implemented for `pallet_assets::Pallet<Runtime>`
          |
          = help: the following other types implement trait `Callable<T>`:
                    frame_system::Pallet<T>
                    pallet_aura::Pallet<T>
                    pallet_authorship::pallet::Pallet<T>
                    pallet_balances::Pallet<T, I>
                    pallet_grandpa::Pallet<T>
                    pallet_randomness_collective_flip::Pallet<T>
                    pallet_session::pallet::Pallet<T>
                    pallet_sudo::Pallet<T>
                  and 3 others
      note: required because it appears within the type `RuntimeCall`
         --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:305:1
          |
      305 |    construct_runtime!(
          |   _^
          |  |_|
          | ||
      306 | ||     pub struct Runtime
      307 | ||     where
      308 | ||         Block = Block,
      ...   ||
      323 | ||     }
      324 | || );
          | ||_- in this macro invocation
      ...   |
      note: required by a bound in `sp_runtime::generic::UncheckedExtrinsic`
         --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/2a0eeff/primitives/runtime/src/generic/unchecked_extrinsic.rs:44:40
          |
      44  | pub struct UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, Call, Signature, Extra>
          |                                        ^^^^ required by this bound in `sp_runtime::generic::UncheckedExtrinsic`
          = note: this error originates in the macro `frame_support::construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
    
      error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied in `RuntimeEvent`
         --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:305:1
          |
      305 |    construct_runtime!(
          |   _^
          |  |_|
          | ||
      306 | ||     pub struct Runtime
      307 | ||     where
      308 | ||         Block = Block,
      ...   ||
      323 | ||     }
      324 | || );
          | ||_- in this macro invocation
      ...   |
          |
      note: required because it appears within the type `RuntimeEvent`
         --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:305:1
          |
      305 |    construct_runtime!(
          |   _^
          |  |_|
          | ||
      306 | ||     pub struct Runtime
      307 | ||     where
      308 | ||         Block = Block,
      ...   ||
      323 | ||     }
      324 | || );
          | ||_- in this macro invocation
      ...   |
      note: required by a bound in `From`
         --> /home/kianoush/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/convert/mod.rs:369:20
          |
      369 | pub trait From<T>: Sized {
          |                    ^^^^^ required by this bound in `From`
          = note: this error originates in the macro `frame_support::construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
    
      error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied in `RuntimeEvent`
         --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:305:1
          |
      305 |    construct_runtime!(
          |   _^
          |  |_|
          | ||
      306 | ||     pub struct Runtime
      307 | ||     where
      308 | ||         Block = Block,
      ...   ||
      323 | ||     }
      324 | || );
          | ||_- in this macro invocation
      ...   |
          |
      note: required because it appears within the type `RuntimeEvent`
         --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:305:1
          |
      305 |    construct_runtime!(
          |   _^
          |  |_|
          | ||
      306 | ||     pub struct Runtime
      307 | ||     where
      308 | ||         Block = Block,
      ...   ||
      323 | ||     }
      324 | || );
          | ||_- in this macro invocation
      ...   |
      note: required by a bound in `TryInto`
         --> /home/kianoush/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/convert/mod.rs:393:23
          |
      393 | pub trait TryInto<T>: Sized {
          |                       ^^^^^ required by this bound in `TryInto`
          = note: this error originates in the macro `frame_support::construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
    
      error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied in `pallet_assets::Event<Runtime>`
         --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:305:1
          |
      305 |    construct_runtime!(
          |   _^
          |  |_|
          | ||
      306 | ||     pub struct Runtime
      307 | ||     where
      308 | ||         Block = Block,
      ...   ||
      323 | ||     }
      324 | || );
          | ||_- in this macro invocation
      ...   |
          |
          = note: required because it appears within the type `pallet_assets::Event<Runtime>`
      note: required by a bound in `From`
         --> /home/kianoush/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/convert/mod.rs:369:16
          |
      369 | pub trait From<T>: Sized {
          |                ^ required by this bound in `From`
          = note: this error originates in the macro `frame_support::construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
    
      error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied in `pallet_assets::Event<Runtime>`
         --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:305:1
          |
      305 |    construct_runtime!(
          |   _^
          |  |_|
          | ||
      306 | ||     pub struct Runtime
      307 | ||     where
      308 | ||         Block = Block,
      ...   ||
      323 | ||     }
      324 | || );
          | ||_- in this macro invocation
      ...   |
          |
          = note: required because it appears within the type `pallet_assets::Event<Runtime>`
      note: required by a bound in `TryInto`
         --> /home/kianoush/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/convert/mod.rs:393:19
          |
      393 | pub trait TryInto<T>: Sized {
          |                   ^ required by this bound in `TryInto`
          = note: this error originates in the macro `frame_support::construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
    
      error[E0277]: the trait bound `Runtime: frame_system::pallet::Config` is not satisfied in `pallet_assets::Event<Runtime>`
         --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:305:1
          |
      305 |    construct_runtime!(
          |   _^
          |  |_|
          | ||
      306 | ||     pub struct Runtime
      307 | ||     where
      308 | ||         Block = Block,
      ...   ||
      323 | ||     }
      324 | || );
          | ||_- in this macro invocation
      ...   |
          |
          = note: required because it appears within the type `pallet_assets::Event<Runtime>`
      note: required by a bound in `Result`
         --> /home/kianoush/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/result.rs:504:17
          |
      504 | pub enum Result<T, E> {
          |                 ^ required by this bound in `Result`
          = note: this error originates in the macro `frame_support::construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
    
      error[E0277]: the trait bound `pallet_assets::Pallet<Runtime>: Callable<Runtime>` is not satisfied in `RuntimeCall`
         --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:305:1
          |
      305 |    construct_runtime!(
          |   _^
          |  |_|
          | ||
      306 | ||     pub struct Runtime
      307 | ||     where
      308 | ||         Block = Block,
      ...   ||
      323 | ||     }
      324 | || );
          | ||_- in this macro invocation
      ...   |
          |
          = help: the following other types implement trait `Callable<T>`:
                    frame_system::Pallet<T>
                    pallet_aura::Pallet<T>
                    pallet_authorship::pallet::Pallet<T>
                    pallet_balances::Pallet<T, I>
                    pallet_grandpa::Pallet<T>
                    pallet_randomness_collective_flip::Pallet<T>
                    pallet_session::pallet::Pallet<T>
                    pallet_sudo::Pallet<T>
                  and 3 others
      note: required because it appears within the type `RuntimeCall`
         --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:305:1
          |
      305 |    construct_runtime!(
          |   _^
          |  |_|
          | ||
      306 | ||     pub struct Runtime
      307 | ||     where
      308 | ||         Block = Block,
      ...   ||
      323 | ||     }
      324 | || );
          | ||_- in this macro invocation
      ...   |
      note: required by a bound in `From`
         --> /home/kianoush/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/convert/mod.rs:369:20
          |
      369 | pub trait From<T>: Sized {
          |                    ^^^^^ required by this bound in `From`
          = note: this error originates in the macro `frame_support::construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
    
      error[E0277]: the trait bound `pallet_assets::Pallet<Runtime>: Callable<Runtime>` is not satisfied
         --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:305:1
          |
      305 |    construct_runtime!(
          |   _^
          |  |_|
          | ||
      306 | ||     pub struct Runtime
      307 | ||     where
      308 | ||         Block = Block,
      ...   ||
      323 | ||     }
      324 | || );
          | ||_- in this macro invocation
      ...   |
          |
          = help: the following other types implement trait `Callable<T>`:
                    frame_system::Pallet<T>
                    pallet_aura::Pallet<T>
                    pallet_authorship::pallet::Pallet<T>
                    pallet_balances::Pallet<T, I>
                    pallet_grandpa::Pallet<T>
                    pallet_randomness_collective_flip::Pallet<T>
                    pallet_session::pallet::Pallet<T>
                    pallet_sudo::Pallet<T>
                  and 3 others
          = note: this error originates in the macro `frame_support::construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
    
      error[E0283]: type annotations needed
         --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:305:1
          |
      305 |    construct_runtime!(
          |   _^
          |  |_|
          | ||
      306 | ||     pub struct Runtime
      307 | ||     where
      308 | ||         Block = Block,
      ...   ||
      323 | ||     }
      324 | || );
          | ||_- in this macro invocation
      ...   |
          |
      note: multiple `impl`s satisfying `RuntimeCall: IsSubType<_>` found
         --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:305:1
          |
      305 |    construct_runtime!(
          |   _^
          |  |_|
          |  |_|
          |  |_|
          |  |_|
          |  |_|
          |  |_|
          | ||
      306 | ||     pub struct Runtime
      307 | ||     where
      308 | ||         Block = Block,
      ...   ||
      323 | ||     }
      324 | || );
          | || -
          | ||_|
          | ||_in this macro invocation
          | ||_in this macro invocation
          | ||_in this macro invocation
          | ||_in this macro invocation
          | ||_in this macro invocation
          | |  in this macro invocation
      ...   |
          = note: this error originates in the macro `frame_support::construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
    
      error[E0283]: type annotations needed
         --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:305:1
          |
      305 |    construct_runtime!(
          |   _^
          |  |_|
          | ||
      306 | ||     pub struct Runtime
      307 | ||     where
      308 | ||         Block = Block,
      ...   ||
      323 | ||     }
      324 | || );
          | ||_- in this macro invocation
      ...   |
          |
      note: multiple `impl`s satisfying `RuntimeCall: From<_>` found
         --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:305:1
          |
      305 |    construct_runtime!(
          |   _^
          |  |_|
          |  |_|
          |  |_|
          |  |_|
          |  |_|
          |  |_|
          | ||
      306 | ||     pub struct Runtime
      307 | ||     where
      308 | ||         Block = Block,
      ...   ||
      323 | ||     }
      324 | || );
          | || -
          | ||_|
          | ||_in this macro invocation
          | ||_in this macro invocation
          | ||_in this macro invocation
          | ||_in this macro invocation
          | ||_in this macro invocation
          | |  in this macro invocation
      ...   |
          = note: this error originates in the macro `frame_support::construct_runtime` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)


and these are:


        rror[E0277]: the trait bound `sp_runtime::generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, ()>, RuntimeCall, MultiSignature, (CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>, CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>, CheckTxVersion<Runtime>, CheckGenesis<Runtime>, CheckEra<Runtime>, CheckNonce<Runtime>, CheckWeight<Runtime>, ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>)>: Decode` is not satisfied
         --> /home/kianoush/projects/substrate_dex/runtime/src/lib.rs:383:32
          |
      383 |         fn initialize_block(header: &<Block as BlockT>::Header) {
          |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Decode` is not implemented for `sp_runtime::generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, ()>, RuntimeCall, MultiSignature, (CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>, CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>, CheckTxVersion<Runtime>, CheckGenesis<Runtime>, CheckEra<Runtime>, CheckNonce<Runtime>, CheckWeight<Runtime>, ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>)>`
          |
          = help: the trait `Decode` is implemented for `sp_runtime::generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<Address, Call, Signature, Extra>`
          = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Codec` for `sp_runtime::generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, ()>, RuntimeCall, MultiSignature, (CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>, CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>, CheckTxVersion<Runtime>, CheckGenesis<Runtime>, CheckEra<Runtime>, CheckNonce<Runtime>, CheckWeight<Runtime>, ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>)>`
          = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `sp_api::BlockT` for `sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, sp_runtime::traits::BlakeTwo256>, sp_runtime::generic::UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, ()>, RuntimeCall, MultiSignature, (CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>, CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>, CheckTxVersion<Runtime>, CheckGenesis<Runtime>, CheckEra<Runtime>, CheckNonce<Runtime>, CheckWeight<Runtime>, ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>)>>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct. There is currently an issue with the template which is fixed [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/pull/407), sorry for the inconvenience.

The issue is that the `Cargo.toml` uses `" branch"` in it instead of `branch`.
If you replace `" branch"` with `branch` *in the whole project* it should work and only give you an error about missing config items.